# Method 'Union' of object '_Global' failed - it works when I step through but not when called

Tags: vba, object, union

I am using a union subroutine to grab data from one sheet, parse it, and place it in another. Why does this code not work when it is called, but works when I step through it?

```
Sub Get_Time_ps()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Row As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("A9")

i = 15
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
Range("A9").Select
Row = Selection.End(xlDown).Row
LastRow = Row - 8
Range("A9").Select
For i = 15 To LastRow Step 6
    Set Rng = Union(Rng, Range("A" & i))
Next i
Row = Rng.Count - 1
Rng.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Raw Data").Select
Range("A23").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Cells.Find("Time").Select
Selection.Copy
Cells.Find("Time").Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(Row, 4)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlFormats


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to have explicit references to the sheet (and workbook if you are using multiple) with range references. It can't unionize ranges from multiple sheets.

Comment: And don't forget to check this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba   Has the way links are created changed?

Answer (score 0):

Code that works one way in the debugger, and then blows up otherwise, 99% of the time means you've got implicit `ActiveSheet` references, and code that is making assumptions about what worksheet is currently active.

`Rng` is assigned to `Range("A9")` so it's off whatever worksheet is active at that time - but then two lines later we `Activate` another sheet (maybe!), and then...

```
Set Rng = Union(Rng, Range("A" & i))
```

If `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate` changed what sheet is currently active, then this `Union` member call will blow up every time, because you can't `Union` two `Range` objects that belong on different worksheets.

[Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) can help you easily find all implicit references to the `ActiveSheet` in your project: consider qualifying them *all* with a proper `Worksheet` object, be explicit about what your intent is, and then as you use `Worksheet` objects instead of implicitly qualifying worksheet member calls with whatever the active sheet is, you'll find that you no longer need to `Select` and `Activate` anything anywhere, and that your code is much more robust and reliable for it.

Removing the `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate` instruction, or moving it before `Rng` is assigned, should "fix" the immediate problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks! That's what it was! I fixed the code. Sorry, beginner here.